# Which path will frames prefer in this setup?

Tags: switch, switching

So I recently installed a long rj45 cable to replace the powerline adapter I was using. I'm keeping the PLA in place as a failover but wanted to know if I will need to swap the connection by hand to make sure packets will take the fastest line to the router or if I can plug both lines to the router at the same time with no issues. Here's the network architecture:

```
            ~150M
        |---PLA----------|       
router--|                |SWITCH---other stuff
        |---RJ45---------|
            GIGABIT
```

Also, is there any significance to which ports are used on the switch (ie. priority)?

Comment: That depends completely on how you have configured your switch and your router.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I can plug both lines to the router at the same time with no
>   issues.

If the ports on the router are actual routed ports, you might be able to configure **one as active and the other as "backup" interface**, if the given vendor supports something like that. Still, chances are that this is not the case. Alternative: LACP between router and switch (see below). Might not be supported on that router.

If however, that router's LAN ports are actually ports of a built-in 4 port switch (and they are on most consumer-grade routers - which would make it off-topic for this site, anyway) and if neither switch nor router-integrated-switch support one variety of a spanning-tree protocol (which consumer-grade "unmanaged" hardware seldom do), you'll just build yourself a 300m packet loop racetrack. It will melt under self-generated/multiplied overload within something like 5 seconds after you hook up the first end device to the switch and it broadcasts its first ARP resolution request into the subnet.

**Ethernet must have a star/tree/cascaded-star topology** (at least logically), so parallel links, rings and loops must be detected and broken up. There's two main features for that:

- Spanning Tree Protocols (802.1d, 802.1w, 802.1s, Cisco (Rapid-)PVST+ and probably some more) detect a loop and put one end of one link into blocking state.
- Link Aggregation (802.3ad, LACP) merges two parallel links (of identical technical nature and speed) into one logical link.

Link-aggeration between a Powerline stretch and a Gigabit link would be asking for trouble, what with the large difference in speed and RTT you'll experience.

But the **most fundamental problem** of the intended setup might be this:

150m is 50% over max length for Cat5e (or better) twisted pair cabling with the usual 8P8C connectors (vulgo: RJ45). You'll be lucky if you can get a usable signal at the other end; with some trickery (like clocking down to 10Mbit/s and by fixing to full duplex mode from both ends), you might get away with it. But probably not at Gigabit speeds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The equipment is consumer grade - no management console or anything, just a dumb switch. I just wasn't sure how "dumb" it really is.  For my purposes there's no issue leaving the auxiliary unplugged and swapping as needed. The PLA was a temporary measure.  As for the cable I'm using, its a 150ft cat-6. The connection speeds are fine, though I probably wouldn't push it much farther without using switches as active repeaters of sorts. It's stupid, but hey, it works, so whatever.

Comment: Ah.. 150ft is a different ballpark than the  "150m" I inferred from the ASCII sketch in your question. That explains why it works :-)